# match first instance of rows containing a unique value in one of two columns, respecting sort order

Tags: mysql, sql, unique, multiple-columns

This is a variation on a question I have seen answered here, but I can't seem to find an answer addressing the following specifics.

Say I have MySQL table "my_table":

```
+----+------+
| id | pid  |
+----+------+
|  1 | NULL | 
|  2 |    1 | 
|  3 | NULL | 
|  4 |    3 | 
+----+------+
```

I want to select rows from this table, but I only want the first row I encounter that has a unique value across either of two specific columns ("id" or "pid"), as opposed to grouping by a unique value in a single column.

However, I also want to respect whatever sort option I'm using. I just want to match on a unique value that comes first, not the MIN() value. I'm looking for a non procedure method of doing this.

In other words, if I ran a SELECT with ORDER BY id ASC, I'd get row id #1 and #3. If I ran a SELECT with ORDER BY id DESC, I'd get row id #2 and #4.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with some simple `where` clause or special option on `having`.

I think you can do it with

```
select id, pid
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where (t2.id = t.id or t2.id = t.pid or 
                         t2.pid = t.id or t2.pid = t.pid
                        ) and
                        t2.id < t.id
                 );
```

The first clause in the nested `where` is looking for unique values.  The second clause `t2.id < t.id` implements the ordering that you want.  In other words, this query is comparing each value in a row to the values in rows "before" it.  How you define "before" is what you mean by ordering.  The above corresponds to `id asc`.  For `id desc`, you would use `t2.id > t.id`.

Comment: Okay, I was afraid this might be the best option. This being a reduction, of course, the sorting might get a little more complicated than a simple ASC/DESC, especially when involving joined tables. But I'll start from here and see where it takes me. Thanks for the quick reply!